# Expressing a complex function $f(x,y)$ as $f(z)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Expressing $g(z)=3x^2+2x-3y^2-1+i(6xy+2y)$ as a function of $z$. Would like hints on what direction to begin? The closest I got was $f(z)=3z^2=3x^2-3y^2+i6xy$, but I am missing 3 terms. How do I do this more systematically? Note that I have set $z=x+iy$.

Comment: All you have to do is to write $x$ as $\frac {z+\overset {-}z} 2$ and $y$ as  $\frac {z-\overset {-}z} {2i}$ and simplify.

Comment: Got it. thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're well on your way! Now, look at the terms you haven't yet written as a function of $z$:
$$
g(z)-f(z)=2x-1+i\cdot2y
$$
Can you express that as a function in $z$, say $h(z)$? If so, then we have
$$
g(z)-f(z)=h(z)\\
g(z)=f(z)+h(z)
$$
and you're done.

Comment: let $h(z)=2z-1$?

Comment: Thank you! But, is there are more systematic approach to this. This problem seems more like a test of my algebraic intuition.

Comment: @TheLastCipher Aaaaaand I'm blind. Of course there is a way, as Kavi Rama Murthy points out above. That being said, I like your approach more. Testing algebraic intuition is more fun than insert-and-calculate.

Comment: It is more fun, but not on a test. haha